# Malliavin Derivative with Mathematica is it possible?

Tags: programming, symbolic, stochastic-calculus

Is it possible to define a  [Malliavin calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malliavin_calculus) with *Mathematica* 9?

Consider a random variables on the Wiener-space $\Omega=\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ of the form $$F=F(\omega)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}h_{t}dW_{t}$$ for some deterministic $h(.)$ in $L^{2}[0,T].$
Here, $\omega$ is a path in the Wiener-space, $\omega \in \Omega$.

We define the Malliavin derivative by

$$
DF=h,\text{ and }D_{t}F=h_{t}.
$$
Let say `MalliavinDer` is this derivative. We have the following rules

1. `MalliavinDer[F_ + G_] := MalliavinDer[F]+MalliavinDer[G]`;
2. `MalliavinDer[F_G_]:=MalliavinDer[F]G+ MalliavinDer[G]F`
3. `MalliavinDer[f(F)]:=f'[F]MalliavinDer[F].`

On the other hand, we have for example:

1. `MalliavinDer[\int_0^T h(t)dWt] := h(t)`
2. `MalliavinDer[W_s] := Piecewise[{{1, s <t}, {0, s >t}}]`
3. `MalliavinDer[f(W_s] := f'[W_s])Piecewise[{{1, s <t}, {0, s >t}}]`

Comment: This question was later cross-posted to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/517874/8348).

Comment: Zbignew, no need to apologize :) While what Arthur said on math.se is generally true (i.e. cross-posts are discouraged), in this case you were justified in doing so — You didn't get an answer on our site in almost 4 months, and it is also too late to migrate (we can't migrate after 60 days). Hope you get an answer soon :)